# Terraform: How to implement s3 backend inside codebuild container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, aws-cdk, aws-codebuild

I am using terraform inside codebuild along with codepipeline ( CI CD ) to deploy my resources. The resources ( all the tf files)  are present as a zip file.

This deployment for CI/CD ( codebuild + codepipeline ) is being done by CDK.

**Now I am confused how and where do I implement terraform s3 backend, because I am using 2 codebuild stages: Plan stage  for terraform planning -> manual approval ( intermediate)  -> Deploy stager for terraform apply )**

```
Conceptually I am not able to understand where should I implement s3 backend.
```

Plan stage code build spec

```
pre_build:
    commands:
      - terraform init

  build:
    commands:
      - echo '{"fruit":{"name":"apple","color":"green","price":1.20}}' | jq '.'
      - terraform plan -no-color -input=false
```

Deploy stage buidspec

```
 pre_build:
        commands:
          - terraform init
    
      build:
        commands:
          - echo '{"fruit":{"name":"apple","color":"green","price":1.20}}' | jq '.'
          - terraform apply -auto-approve -no-color -input=false
```

Comment: The s3 backend needs to be configured by whatever created the pipelines, in this case most likely the CDK.

Comment: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cdktf/concepts/remote-backends